# Constructor already in class

Tags: java, constructor

```
    private Square wall;
public House()
{
    wall = new Square();
    wall.makeVisible();
    wall.changeSize(80);
    wall.moveHorizontal(40);
    wall.moveVertical(170);
}

private Triangle roof;
public House()
{
    roof = new Triangle();
    roof.makeVisible();
    roof.changeSize(50, 120);
    roof.moveHorizontal(90);
    roof.moveVertical(155);
    roof.changeColor("Black");
}
```

Edit: That fixed it but when I try adding this one I get the error again.

```
private Square window;
public House(Square window)
{
window = new Square();
}
```

I understand why I am getting this, because I already have 2 of the same constructors with the same signature. Is there anyway I could just merge them together?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to handle multiple constructors in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581873/best-way-to-handle-multiple-constructors-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe considering constructor overloading
. Overloading is a technique in which a class can have any number of constructors that differ in parameter list the reason why your code was not working it was because you have 2 constructors with same parameters.

```
private Square wall;
public House(Square wall)
{
    this.wall = new Square();
    this.wall.makeVisible();
    this.wall.changeSize(80);
    this.wall.moveHorizontal(40);
    this.wall.moveVertical(170);
}

private Triangle roof;
public House(Triangle roof)
{
    this.roof = new Triangle();
    this.roof.makeVisible();
    this.roof.changeSize(50, 120);
    this.roof.moveHorizontal(90);
    this.roof.moveVertical(155);
    this.roof.changeColor("Black");
}
```

Comment: No problem @JavaLearner dont forget to mark the answer as a correct one if it fixed your problem :)

Comment: another question if I was wanting to add another constructor with the class house while using square how would I go by doing that

Comment: check recent edit

Comment: Just add a constructor with all these atributes as a parameter 
public House(Triange roof,Square wall,Square window) {
then here you initialize them

Answer (score 0):

yes!
you could do someting like this:

```
public House()
{
    wall = new Square();
    wall.makeVisible();
    wall.changeSize(80);
    wall.moveHorizontal(40);
    wall.moveVertical(170);
    roof = new Triangle();
    roof.makeVisible();
    roof.changeSize(50, 120);
    roof.moveHorizontal(90);
    roof.moveVertical(155);
    roof.changeColor("Black");
}
```

Comment: Sure! @JavaLearner please mark the answer as a correct one if it helped you!